# Facebook Graph API : Publish to offline user, with user Facebook ID and access_token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using PHP/MySQL, and I want to publish for some offline users, I have already both permissions for publish_stream and offline_access, how to publish with the Graph API to this user wall, I already stored users ID's and access_token in my Database.

how to do that ??

the current code is not working for me, the php file stop execution at this line :

```
$result = $facebook->api('/'.$users[fid].'/feed?access_token='.$users[session].'/', 'post', $attachment);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your $attachment data is properly formatted. Also your post string is wrong, try:

```
$result = $facebook->api('/'.$users[fid].'/feed?access_token='.$users[session], 'post', $attachment);
```

Also make sure your `offline_access` token is valid

Comment: Thank you, I already get the code working by posting via Curl, and this code also works.

Comment: Can you please explain your code??What is the format for $attachment and what is Post??Is this code work in new PHP SDK???